# How to translate views exposed filter

Tags: drupal, localization, drupal-7, translate, drupal-taxonomy

I have taxonomy term field in acount fields list. I translated this term (using Translation mode: "Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized." ). Now i have view which displays and filters registered users. problem for me is that . exposed filter for this term is only in one language. pls help.

Answer (score 2):

Download and enable [Internationalization Views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module, to be able to get the localized taxonomy term names.

Comment: i allready did it , but it dose not works for me.
here is my view - > http://iesdata.iliauni.edu.ge/cv/?q=en/cvs
i am tolking about this filter --> ტერმ (field_term)  last one

Comment: Are there translated versions for your taxonomy terms?

Comment: yes if you change languge (from top left corner ) language flags(icons). you will see  in views row (second person) for 
english -> ტერმ:
val1, val2
and for georgian-> ტერმ:
ვალ1, ვალ2

Comment: It works but you need to re-add your field into filter criteria (or to be more exact add a new one and delete untranslated). The name of the field will be something like "Content: Type (field_project_type) (translated)" (as opposed to: "Content: Type (field_project_type)"